# MySQL REGEXP usage within Boolean Match/Against

Tags: mysql, regex, match, against

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT title, description 
FROM some_table 
WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('+denver (REGEXP "[[:<:]]colorado[s]*[[:>:]]")' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

the "regexp" here looks for a "complete word" colorado (with or without the ending "s").

I want to actually select only those rows that have ("denver") AND ("colorado" or "colorados"). But I cannot put a "+" for the REGEXP. I tried but got 0 results, although there are rows in the table that match the requirement.

Any ideas on how I can get the "+" to work within against using a REGEXP?
I am constructing this from within a PHP script where "denver" and "colorado" are values of variables I use to construct the select statement.

My PHP/MySQL script would look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT title, description 
FROM some_table 
WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('+$var1 (REGEXP "[[:<:]]$var2[s]*[[:>:]]")' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to combine regular expressions and MATCH ... IN BOOLEAN MODE. You need to use the syntax for writing boolean expressions.

- [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Try something like this:

```
SELECT title, description
FROM some_table
WHERE MATCH (title,description)
      AGAINST ('+denver +(colorado colorados)' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. But that would also pick up rows with "denver abcolorado" or even "denver whatever 123colorado890". My requirement is pick only the complete word found in $var2 and its plural. I may need to construct that query in PHP probably. Please let me know if you have any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @Sameer: Are you sure? Have you tested it? See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d971f/1

Comment: Amazing! Honestly, had not tried it thinking it would pick up the other rows too. I admit I have a lot more to learn! Thanks a bunch Mark!