# MySQL fulltext split on letters/numbers

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I have a table of products, e.g. cars. I want users to be able to search using multiple terms, e.g. for autocompletion. LIKE %term% is way to slow, because it's huge table. In order to make it fast, I want to use MySQL's fulltext search. I use ft_min_word_lenght = 1.

Imagine the productname is "Lexus RX450H". Then two words are indexed: "Lexus" and "RX450H".

```
MATCH (productname) AGAINST ('+lex* +rx45*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ')
```

..will match this product, good.

but

```
MATCH (productname) AGAINST ('+lex* +450*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ')
```

wont, because it's imperative to search on begin of words.

Users might know the number, but might forget the letters. I want the second query to match.

If product was:
"Lexus RX 450 H", then the last query would have matched, problem solved.

What I could do is create a second column in the table and split all letters/numbers by putting a space in between them, e.g. using regexp. Then, the search should be done on this column, voila, problem solved.

However, the (big) table will become almost twice as big and I was wondering whether it is possible to tell MySQL to perform the indexing like described, without creating an extra column.

Comment: Here is the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731187/mysql-regexp-usage-within-boolean-match-against But he thinks, it's not possible to combine regex with BOOLEN MODE

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the query is returning rows as it should.

> MATCH (productname) AGAINST ('+lex* +450*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ')

Essentially says match text that begins with 'lex' and **begins with** '450'.  Your data matches on the 'lex' but not on the '450'.  Remove the asterisk on the '+405' and I believe that will work for you.

MATCH (productname) AGAINST ('+lex* +450' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ')

should return 'Lexus RX 450 H' and 'Lexus RX450H'.